# Finding the coefficient of $x^7$ in the expansion $(1 + x)^{23}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**By definition**, the *Binomial Theorem* states:

$$(x+y)^n = {n\choose 0}x^n + {n\choose 1}x^{n-1}y + {n\choose 2}x^{n-2}y^2 + \cdots + {n \choose {n-1}}xy^{n-1} + {n \choose n}y^n$$

For any $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.

Now I know I could expand this simply by using the binomial theorem as stated above and just look at the coefficient of $x$ where $n = 7$, however that gets very lengthy, especially when - like in this case - our $n$ is a large number.

I was hoping for a better understanding through an explanation of how I may go about tackling this problem *without* expanding to the $n$th term.

Comment: Just put $y=1$. You only have to look at a single term.

Comment: If I set y = 1 (like I have in the title), at which term from the expansion am I curious about?

Comment: Then you have $(1+x)^{23}=1+23x+\dots+{23\choose7}x^7+\dots+x^{23}$.

Comment: It will be the one with 7 at the bottom. It can help to know that n choose k is symmetric.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see your difficulty. Put $x=1$ in the binomial expansion and you have $(1+y)^n=1+{n\choose1}y+{n\choose2}y^2+\dots+{n\choose k}y^k+\dots+y^n$. Alternatively remember that ${n\choose n-k}={n\choose k}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expansion of $(a+x)^n$, the general term, that is the $(r+1)^{th}$ term  is $$T_{r+1}=\binom nr a^{n-r}x^r.$$

Thus, in the expansion of $(1+x)^{23}$, the general term is $$\binom{23}r1^{23-r}x^r.$$

You want the coefficient of $x^7$, that is $r=7$, so the the coefficient is $$\binom{23}7.$$

This is the way, using general terms, you can derive any coefficient of any term without any expansion.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for; a clear and simply form. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The coefficient of $x^7$ will be

$$\binom{23}7=\frac{23!}{7!16!}.$$

An efficient way to compute that ratio is by incrementally evaluating $\binom{23}k$ for increasing $k$, as these are simply related to each other and are integer.

$$\binom{23}0=1,\\
\binom{23}1=1\frac{23}1=23,\\
\binom{23}2=23\cdot\frac{22}2=23\cdot11,\\
\binom{23}3=23\cdot11\cdot\frac{21}3=23\cdot11\cdot7,\\
\binom{23}4=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot\frac{20}{4}=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot5,\\
\binom{23}5=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot5\cdot\frac{19}{5}=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot19,\\
\binom{23}6=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot19\cdot\frac{18}{6}=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot19\cdot3,\\
\binom{23}7=23\cdot11\cdot7\cdot19\cdot3\cdot\frac{17}{7}=23\cdot11\cdot19\cdot3\cdot17.$$

Hence

$$245157\,x^7.$$

(You can also write the long fraction and simplify.)

Comment: +1 Because I find it depressing that a statement of something that the OP and others can memorise for mindless application attracts 6  votes plus a green tick, whilst a useful explanation of some theory only attracts 1!

Comment: @almagest: they call it democracy :)

Comment: @almagest: democracy strikes back, it seems...

Comment: @SubhadeepDey My comment was not meant as a criticism of you. I agree with you, if that is what the OP wants, then someone should provide it. My comment simply an expression of my depression that in a site where most of the questions are asked by undergraduates so many of them should upvote this kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use the *[coefficient of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Introduction)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> This way we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^7](1+x)^{23}&=[x^7]\sum_{n=0}^{23}\binom{23}{n}x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{23}{7}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{23!}{7!16!}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)*
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^7$