# Simplify a sum with a product and multinomial coefficient

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

This is a follow-up question to my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048704/simplifying-the-sum-of-a-product-of-multinomial-coefficients/4049342#4049342), where I've got a great help! (I created a new one to avoid editing the original one).
Can the following sum be simplified?

$$
 \sum_{\substack{k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_m &=& B \\ g_1 + g_2 + \ldots + g_m &=& W}} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}k_i\right) \cdot {B \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots k_m} \cdot {W \choose g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_m}
$$
where $B + W = n$, and $\forall_i: g_i = x - k_i$, where $x = \frac{n}{m}$, and $m\mid n$ and $k_i \geq 1$

I tried to follow the steps suggested in my previous post, but I got stuck. For $m=2$ I've got the following
$$
\sum_{\substack{k_1 + k_2 &=& B \\ k_1, k_2 &\geq& 0}} k_1 \cdot k_2 \cdot {B \choose k_1, k_2} \cdot {2N - B \choose N-k_1, N-k_2} \\ = \sum_{\substack{k_1 + k_2 &=& B \\ k_1, k_2 &\geq& 0}} k_2 \cdot {B \choose k_1-1} \cdot {2N - B \choose N-k_1, N-k_2} \\
= \sum_{k_1 = 0}^B \left(B-k_1 \right) \cdot {B \choose k_1-1} \cdot {2N - B \choose N-k_1} \\ 
$$
From the previous post I know how to handle the binomial coefficients, but I'm not sure what can I do now with the $B-k_1$ factor inside the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
S = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
   {g_{\,1}  + g_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,g_{\,m}  = W}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {k_{\,i} } } \right)
\left( \matrix{ B \cr  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,k_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)
\left( \matrix{W \cr g_{\,1} ,\,g_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,g_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)} 
$$

plus the added conditions
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  B + W = n \hfill \cr 
  g_{\,i}  = x - k_{\,i}  \hfill \cr 
  1 \le k_{\,i}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Leave apart for the moment the fact that $x=n/m, \; m | n$.
Because of the product, we can consider $0 \le ki$, and for the multinomial not to be null it shall be
$0 \le g_i$.

Thus  the set of conditions becomes (if I understood them properly)
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,i} ,\;g_{\,i} \, \le \,x}  \cr 
   {g_{\,i}  = x - k_{\,i} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
   {g_{\,1}  + g_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,g_{\,m}  = W}  \cr 
 } } \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,i} ,\;g_{\,i} \, \le \,x}  \cr 
   {g_{\,i}  = x - k_{\,i} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
   {\left( {x - k_{\,1} } \right) + \left( {x - k_{\,2} } \right)
 + \, \ldots  + \,\left( {x - k_{\,m} } \right) = W}  \cr 
 } } \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,i} ,\;g_{\,i} \, \le \,x}  \cr 
   {g_{\,i}  = x - k_{\,i} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
   {W + B = mx = n}  \cr 
 } } \right. \cr} 
$$

Under these conditions the summand can be rewritten as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {k_{\,i} } } \right)
\left( \matrix{ B \cr  k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,k_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)
\left( \matrix{ W \cr  g_{\,1} ,\,g_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,g_{\,m}  \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {k_{\,i} } } \right){{B!} \over {k_{\,1} !\,k_{\,2} !\, \cdots \,k_{\,m} !}}
{{\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {x - k_{\,1} } \right)!\,\left( {x - k_{\,2} } \right)!\, \cdots \,\left( {x - k_{\,m} } \right)!}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {x!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {k_{\,i} } } \right){{x!} \over {k_{\,1} !\,\left( {x - k_{\,1} } \right)!}}
{{x!} \over {k_{\,2} !\,\left( {x - k_{\,2} } \right)!}} \cdots {{x!} \over {k_{\,m} !\,\left( {x - k_{\,m} } \right)!}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {x!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {{{x\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k_{\,i}  - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k_{\,i}  - 1} \right)!\,}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {{{\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k_{\,i}  - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k_{\,i}  - 1} \right)!\,}}}  =
 {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left( \matrix{ x - 1 \cr  k_{\,i}  - 1 \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$
so that the sum becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(B,m,x)\quad \left| {\;1\, \le mx \le B} \right.\quad  =   \cr
 &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,k_{\,i} ,\;g_{\,i} \, \le \,x}  \cr 
   {g_{\,i}  = x - k_{\,i} }  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
   {g_{\,1}  + g_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,g_{\,m}  = W}  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {k_{\,i} } } \right)
\left( \matrix{B \cr k_{\,1} ,\,k_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,k_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)
\left( \matrix{ W \cr g_{\,1} ,\,g_{\,2} ,\, \ldots ,\,g_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k_{\,i} \,\left( { \le \,x} \right)}  \cr 
   {k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,k_{\,m}  = B}  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left( \matrix{ x - 1 \cr  k_{\,i}  - 1 \cr}  \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{ {\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j_{\,i} \,\left( { \le \,x - 1} \right)}  \cr 
   {j_{\,1}  + j_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,j_{\,m}  = B - m}  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left( \matrix{ x - 1 \cr  j_{\,i}  \cr}  \right)} }  \cr} 
$$

Now, since
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\left( {1 + z} \right)^{x - 1} } \right)^{\,m}
  = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j_{\,i} \,\left( { \le \,x - 1} \right)}
 {\left( \matrix{ x - 1 \cr  j_{\,i}  \cr}  \right)z^{\,j_{\,i} } } } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s\, \le \,m\,\left( {x - 1} \right)}
 {\sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{ {\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j_{\,i} \,\left( { \le \,x - 1} \right)}  \cr 
   {j_{\,1}  + j_{\,2}  + \, \ldots  + \,j_{\,m}  = \,s}  \cr 
 } } \right.}
 {\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^m {\left( \matrix{ x - 1 \cr j_{\,i}  \cr}  \right)} } \right)z^{\,s} } }  \cr} 
$$
we conclude that
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & S(B,m,x)\quad \left| {\;1\, \le mx \le B} \right.\quad  =   \cr
 & = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\;\;\left[ {z^{\,B - m} } \right]\left( {1 + z} \right)^{m\left( {x - 1} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\;\;\left( \matrix{ m\left( {x - 1} \right) \cr  B - m \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!\left( {mx - B} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}
\;{{\left( {m\left( {x - 1} \right)} \right)!} \over {\left( {B - m} \right)!\left( {mx - B} \right)!}}\; =   \cr 
  &  = {{B!} \over {\left( {B - m} \right)!}}\;
{{\left( {m\left( {x - 1} \right)} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }}\;
 = \left( \matrix{ B \cr  m \cr}  \right)\;
{{m!\left( {m\left( {x - 1} \right)} \right)!} \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)!} \right)^{\,m} }} \cr} 
}$$

*--- in reply to your comment  ---*

Consider the following simple case
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {1 + z} \right)^a \left( {1 + z} \right)^a
  = \left( {\sum\limits_{k_1 } {\left( \matrix{ a \cr  k_1  \cr}  \right)z^{k_1 } } } \right)
\left( {\sum\limits_{k_2 } {\left( \matrix{ a \cr   k_2  \cr}  \right)z^{k_2 } } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^2 {\left( {\sum\limits_{k_i }
 {\left( \matrix{a \cr k_i  \cr}  \right)z^{k_i } } } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k_1 } {\sum\limits_{k_2 }
 {\left( \matrix{ a \cr  k_1  \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ a \cr k_2  \cr}  \right)z^{k_1  + k_2 } } }
  = \sum\limits_s {\sum\limits_{k_1  + k_2  = s}
 {\left( \matrix{a \cr k_1  \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{a \cr   k_2  \cr}  \right)z^s } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_s {\left( {\sum\limits_{k_1  + k_2  = s} {\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^2
 {\left( \matrix{ a \cr  k_i  \cr}  \right)} } \right)} } \right)z^s }
  = \sum\limits_s {\left( \matrix{ 2a \cr   s \cr}  \right)z^s }  \cr} 
$$
which implies
$$
\sum\limits_{k_1  + k_2  = s} {\left( {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^2
 {\left( \matrix{a \cr  k_i  \cr}  \right)} } \right)}
  = \left( \matrix{ 2a \cr   s \cr}  \right)
$$
and which is just the Vandermonde convolution.

Comment: It seems you don't properly respect the relationship between $g_i$ and $k_i$. You might want to check OP's referenced post.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Oops, thanks,  I mislooked  them.  I recasted my answer considering them

Comment: @GCab Just going through your solution. Do you mind clarifying the equalities regarding swapping the product and sum for $((1+z)^{x-1})^m$?

Comment: I added a note about: is it clear ?

Comment: @GCab Yes, it is clear! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helps. It is an interesting problem, only that the conditions on the indices $k,g$ were complicated to be interpreted: does my understanding of them comply with what you meant to say ?

Comment: @GCab: I've added a note showing that our answers coincide. Good work! (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: it's always excellent to have a double check ! (+1) to your work as well.

Comment: Big thank you to both of you! I've learned a lot from your solutions!

Comment: @SugerBoy: good, I also could better sistemize my knowledges on multinomials !

Answer (score 2):

We assume positive integers $m,n\geq 2$. Since $m\mid n$ we know that $n=Nm$ is a multiple of $m$ with $N\geq 1$. This way we can write $W=Nm-B$ and $x=N$. We show by induction of $m$ that for all $N\geq 1, m\leq B\leq Nm$ the following is valid:

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_m=B\\k_1,\ldots,k_m\geq 0}}
\binom{B}{k_1,\ldots,k_m}\binom{mN-B}{N-k_1,\ldots,N-k_m}=B^{\underline{m}}\prod_{q=2}^m\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

with $B^{\underline{m}}=B(B-1)\cdots(B-m+1)$ the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*.

> **Base step: $m=2$**
>
> We obtain for natural numbers $B,N$ with $2\leq B\leq  2N$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{\substack{k_1+k_2=B\\k_1,k_2\geq 0}}}&\color{blue}{k_1k_2\binom{B}{k_1,k_2}\binom{2N-B}{N-k_1,N-k_2}}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^{B}k_1\left(B-k_1\right)\binom{B}{k_1}\binom{2N-B}{N-k_1}\tag{1}\\
> &=B\sum_{k_1=1}^{B-1}\left(B-k_1\right)\binom{B-1}{B-k_1}\binom{2N-B}{N-k_1}\tag{2}\\
> &=B(B-1)\sum_{k_1=1}^{B-1}\binom{B-2}{k_1-1}\binom{2N-B}{N-k_1}\tag{3}\\
> &=B^{\underline{2}}\sum_{k_1=0}^{B-2}\binom{B-2}{k_1}[z^{N-k_1-1}](1+z)^{2N-B}\tag{4}\\
> &=B^{\underline{2}}[z^{N-1}](1+z)^{2N-B}(1+z)^{B-2}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=B^{\underline{2}}\binom{2(N-1)}{N-1}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the multinomial as binomial coefficients, substituting $k_2=B-k_1$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{p-q}$ and we skip the indices $k_1=0$ and $k_1=B$ which do not contribute to the sum.
- In (3) we use again $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{p-q}$ as in (2) and (3).
- In (4) we shift the index $k_1$ by one to start with $k_1=0$. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^N]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^N$ of a series.
- In (5) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $z^{N-1}$.

**Induction hypothesis: $m=M$**

We assume the validity of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_M=B\\k_1,\ldots,k_M\geq 0}}
\binom{B}{k_1,\ldots,k_M}\binom{MN-B}{N-k_1,\ldots,N-k_M}=B^{\underline{M}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

**Induction step: $m=M+1$**

We have to show
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_{M+1}=B\\k_1,\ldots,k_{M+1}\geq 0}}
\binom{B}{k_1,\ldots,k_{M+1}}\binom{(M+1)N-B}{N-k_1,\ldots,N-k_{M+1}}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{=B^{\underline{{M+1}}}\prod_{q=2}^{M+1}\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}}\tag{8}
\end{align*}

We obtain for $M\geq 2$:
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_{M+1}=B\\k_1,\ldots,k_{M+1}\geq 0}}
\binom{B}{k_1,\ldots,k_{M+1}}\binom{(M+1)N-B}{N-k_1,\ldots,N-k_{M+1}}}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{k_{M+1}=1}^{B-1}k_{M+1}\frac{B!}{k_{M+1}!(B-k_{M+1})!}\,\frac{((M+1)N-B)!}{(N-k_{M+1})!(MN-(B-k_{M+1}))!}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_{M}=B-k_{M+1}\\k_1,\ldots,k_{M}\geq 0}}
\binom{B-k_{M+1}}{k_1,\ldots,k_{M}}\binom{MN-(B-k_{M+1})}{N-k_1,\ldots,N-k_{M}}\tag{9}\\
&=B\sum_{k_{M+1}=1}^{B-1}\binom{B-1}{B-k_{M+1}}\binom{(M+1)N-B}{N-k_{M+1}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(B-k_{M+1}\right)^{\underline{M}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{q}\tag{10}\\
&=B\sum_{k_{M+1}=1}^{B-M+1}\frac{(B-1)^{\underline{M}}}{(B-k_{M+1})^{\underline{M}}}\binom{B-M-1}{B-k_{M+1}-M+1}\binom{(M+1)N-B}{N-k_{M+1}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(B-k_{M+1}\right)^{\underline{M}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{q}\\
&=B^{\underline{M+1}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}
\sum_{k_{M+1}=0}^{B-M}\binom{B-M-1}{k_{M+1}}\binom{(M+1)N-B}{N-k_{M+1}-1}\\
&=B^{\underline{M+1}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}
\sum_{k_{M+1}=0}^{B-M}\binom{B-M-1}{k_{M+1}}[z^{N-k_{M+1}-1}](1+z)^{(M+1)N-B}\\
&=B^{\underline{M+1}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}
[z^{N-1}](1+z)^{(M+1)N-B}(1+z)^{B-M-1}\\
&=B^{\underline{M+1}}\prod_{q=2}^M\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}\binom{(M+1)N-M-1}{N-1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=B^{\underline{M+1}}\prod_{q=2}^{M+1}\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}}\\
\end{align*}
in accordance with (8) and the claim follows.

**Comment:**

- In (9) we separate $k_{M+1}$ and expand to get binomial coefficients in the next step.
- In (10) we apply the induction hypothesis.

---

**Note:** We obtain from (1):
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{B^{\underline{m}}\prod_{q=2}^m\binom{q(N-1)}{N-1}}
&=B^{\underline{m}}\cdot\frac{\prod_{q=2}^m\left(q(N-1)\right)!}{\prod_{q=2}^m(N-1)!\prod_{q=2}^m\left((q-1)(N-1)\right)!}\\
&=B^{\underline{m}}\cdot\frac{\prod_{q=2}^m\left(q(N-1)\right)!}{\left((N-1)!\right)^{m-1}\prod_{q=1}^{m-1}\left(q(N-1)\right)!}\\
&=B^{\underline{m}}\cdot\frac{\left(m(N-1)\right)!}{\left((N-1)!\right)^{m}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{B}{m}\frac{m!\left(m(N-1)\right)!}{\left((N-1)!\right)^{m}}}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the answer from @GCab.

Comment: Hi, Markus, something doesn't "run" in your answer, or maybe I did not catch OP question ?

Comment: @Markus Thanks a lot! Do you mind adding the final general form (for any ) so that I can accept the answer?

Comment: @SugerBoy: Final form added.

Comment: Big thank you to both of you! I've learned a lot from your solutions!

Comment: @SugerBoy: You're welcome! :-)